# Active Directory Implementation

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

I am planning to implement active directory on Windows Server 2003.  Right now there is no AD setup in the network.  We have about 80 users in this location and 300 other users across various locations.

Have few questions here:

1. Should I assign local IP or should I go for static IP right away (DNS)?
2. Which tool/strategy should I use to create existing users in AD?
3. If I use local IP and decentralize AD across locations will I be able to integrate at a later time?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best to use a local, static IP address for an AD/DNS server.

If the other 300 users are in various locations you need an AD design that accounts for the network topology and latency between networks.

Microsoft's Technet documentation can get you started in AD design.

Comment: we are planning for AD implementation across three cities in two different countries.  do we need static ip for all domain controllers? and also do we need to be on T1 or require VPN across sites??

Answer (score 0):

You will need a VPN (or WAN link) between these sites to do replication. I would not do AD Repl directly over the Internet.

Not sure what you mean by static IP - as in like static IP from the ISP? These should be internal IPs. Use a VPN or private WAN for inter site communication.

Comment: So far I have the following notes:
Identify one server from each site for AD setup on existing Windows 2003 machines.
Configure Active Directory on each of these Windows 2003 machines.
Create users using AD in one location.
*Still not sure how to configure servers running AD for replication,  DNS setup for these three locations, IP configuration (static vs dynamic)